# Adding Crashlytics to Xcode

Tags: xcode, crashlytics

Upon adding a Run Script Build Phase, my app fails to build due to `Shell Script Invocation Error: Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2`. When I delete the Run Script Build Phase, my app builds perfectly. What's the best way of troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same error happened in one of my projects too. But it happened because I mistakenly deleted the `Crashlytics` App from my system. So, please make sure, it is installed on your system. 
So there are basically two solutions to it.

- Install `Fabric` App (as I don't think you will be able to find `Crashlytics` app), and this error will go away
- Upgrade your Project to `Fabric`, i.e update SDKs etc